# DLL Methods Inaccessible in C# but not in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll

I'm in the process of converting a legacy VB.NET application into a C# application.  The VB.NET application references an external .DLL (ExternalLib.dll) that has the class `MyClass` which implements `IMyClass`.

In VB.NET, this code compiles and executes without problems:

```
Dim external As New MyClass
external.DoMethod(1)
```

In C#, this code throws a compile-time error:

```
MyClass external = new MyClass();
external.DoMethod(1);
```

> 'ExternalLib.MyClass' does not contain a definition for 'DoMethod' and
>   no extension method 'DoMethod' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ExternalLib.MyClass' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Looking at the metadata, `IMyClass` doesn't have `DoMethod()`. In VB.NET's Intellisense, `DoMethod()` does not show up among the other available public methods, but everything compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: Is the VB.NET code set to `option strict on` or `off`? It might be late-binding. Where does `IMyClass` come into it exactly? You don't seem to be using it..

Comment: Change C#@ to `IMyClass external = ...` and it will likely work too.

Comment: IMyClass shows up when I use "Go to Definition" and has several methods that don't include DoMethod().  I thought that info might be helpful.  The compile settings in the VB.NET app are: Option explicit: On, Option strict: Off, Option compare: Binary, Option infer: Off

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It didn't work. :(  Same error.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - I think you gave me an idea.  I'm going to test out changing `MyClass external` to `dynamic external` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VB.NET application is using late-binding with `option strict off` to access the hidden method in ExternalLib.dll.  Using the `dynamic` keyword allows for the same behavior in the C# application:

```
dynamic external = new MyClass();
external.DoMethod(1);
```

*(Kudos to Blorgbeard for pointing me in the right direction.)*

Answer (score 1):

Is `DoMethod()` a static method or an instance method? If it was a static method that would explain why you can't see it in the interface. You need to change your C# code to this:

```
MyClass.DoMethod(1);
```

Comment: Good call - VB allows you to call a static method via an instance, which would explain the op's case (but C# would normally issue a more useful error message...).

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a static method.  `MyClass.DoMethod(1)` results in `'ExternalLib.MyClass' does not contain a definition for 'DoMethod'`